# Creating liquid 3 column divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have the typical 3 column setup. Each column is a div. Looks something like this:

```
          ---------------------
          |     |      |      |
          |DIV1 | DIV2 | DIV3 |
          |     |      |      |
          ---------------------
```

But I want to make it so that once the divs no longer fit in the user's window or they load the site on mobile, the divs will rearrange themselves in a vertical manner. Like so:

```
          |     |
          |DIV1 |
          |     |
          -------
          |     |
          |DIV2 |
          |     |
          -------
          |     |
          |DIV3 |
          |     |
```

Any way I could go about this?

Comment: Take a look at `Bootstrap`.

Comment: Use responsive web design with media queries

Comment: this depends very much on the way you are styling your grid and the content they have. We will need your code to be able to provide a relevant answer. With or without media queries

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), but usually when you make floating divs, they stack vertically when there isn't enough space, unless you have some specific case where it doesn't work.

Comment: Need to use media queries, yet only a specific use case precludes floats? Which method are you suggesting here?

Comment: I am saying that your sentence doesn't make sense. If you *need to* use media queries, why mention floats. You could say that I'm encouraging you to expand on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/ELMEt/16/) fiddle.

You need to use media query to change the display property on specific window size.

Set display as `inline-block` if width is greater than 600px else `block`.

Comment: @vp_arth 2+1 combination?

Comment: @khakiout earlier it was. downvoter can you please remove your downvote now.

Comment: Yes, now it's correct media-queried responsive design

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/GAX2a/)

Use media queries according to your screen size. Use min and max-width properties.

```
@media all and (min-width: 321px)
{
 div
 {
     float: left;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple example

http://jsfiddle.net/willHsu/RLmpM/

```
div{
    border: solid 1px black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float : left;
}
```

you can add a `float: left` in css, than the div will move down whenever no longer fit in window.

plus add a mobile query to make it fit one the mobile

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="col">col1</div>
    <div class="col">col2</div>
    <div class="col">col3</div>
</div>
<style>
    .wrap
    {
        margin: auto;
    }
    .wrap .col
    {
        width: 200px;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        border: solid 1px #000;
        height: 200px;
    }
</style>
```

div automatically align vertically if they don't get space in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries after a specific screen resolution you need

```
div
{
 float:left;
 width: 30%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 640px)
{
 div
 {
  clear:both;
  width : 100%;
 }
}
```